# How to check the overlapping time intervals from one type 2 SCD dimension

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have one problem identifying and fixing some records having overlapping time intervals, for one scd type 2 dimension.
   What I have is:

```
Bkey   Uid  startDate                       endDate
'John'  1   1990-01-01 (some time stamp)    2017-01-10 (some time stamp)
'John'  2   2016-11=03 (some time stamp)    2016-11-14 (some time stamp)
'John'  3   2016-11-14 (some time stamp)    2016-12-29 (some time stamp)
'John'  4   2016-12-29 (some time stamp)    2017-01-10 (some time stamp)
'John'  5   2017-01-10 (some time stamp)    2017-04-22 (some time stamp)
......
```

I want to find (first) which are all the Johns having overlapping time periods, for a table having lots and lots of Johns and then to figure out a way to correct those overlapping time periods. For the latest I know there are some function LAGG, LEAD, which can handle that, but it eludes me how to find those over lappings.
Any hints?
Regards,

Comment: To correct it : Split every interval to the atoms (single day), DISTINCT, find islands.

Comment: I've added section [Edit 1] with declaration of @Groups table variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ 1 ] Following query will return overlapping time ranges:

```
SELECT  *,
        (
            SELECT  *
            FROM    @Dimension1 y
            WHERE   x.Bkey = y.Bkey
            AND     x.Uid <> y.Uid
            AND     NOT(x.startDate > y.endDate OR x.endDate < y.startDate)
            FOR XML RAW, ROOT, TYPE
        ) OverlappingTimeRanges
FROM    @Dimension1 x
```

Full script:

```
DECLARE @Dimension1 TABLE (
    Bkey        VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Uid         INT NOT NULL,
    startDate   DATE NOT NULL,
    endDate     DATE NOT NULL,
        CHECK(startDate < endDate)
);
INSERT  @Dimension1 
SELECT 'John',  1,   '1990-01-01', '2017-01-10' UNION ALL
SELECT 'John',  2,   '2016-11-03', '2016-11-14' UNION ALL
SELECT 'John',  3,   '2016-11-14', '2016-12-29' UNION ALL
SELECT 'John',  4,   '2016-12-29', '2017-01-10' UNION ALL
SELECT 'John',  5,   '2017-01-11', '2017-04-22';

SELECT  *,
        (
            SELECT  *
            FROM    @Dimension1 y
            WHERE   x.Bkey = y.Bkey
            AND     x.Uid <> y.Uid
            AND     NOT(x.startDate > y.endDate OR x.endDate < y.startDate)
            FOR XML RAW, ROOT, TYPE
        ) OverlappingTimeRanges
FROM    @Dimension1 x
```

**[Demo here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=81df7ebab65172835f095c993f211528)**

[ 2 ] In order to find distinct groups of time ranges with overlapping original rows I would use following approach:

```
-- Edit 1
DECLARE @Groups TABLE (
    Bkey            VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Uid             INT NOT NULL,
    startDateNew    DATE NOT NULL,
    endDateNew      DATE NOT NULL,
        CHECK(startDateNew < endDateNew)
);
INSERT  @Groups
SELECT  x.Bkey, x.Uid, z.startDateNew, z.endDateNew
FROM    @Dimension1 x
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT  MIN(y.startDate) AS startDateNew, MAX(y.endDate) AS endDateNew
    FROM    @Dimension1 y
    WHERE   x.Bkey = y.Bkey
    AND     NOT(x.startDate > y.endDate OR x.endDate < y.startDate)
) z
-- End of Edit 1

-- This returns distinct groups identified by DistinctGroupId together with all overlapping Uid(s) from current group
SELECT  *
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY b.Bkey, b.startDateNew, b.endDateNew) AS DistinctGroupId, b.*
    FROM (
        SELECT  DISTINCT a.Bkey, a.startDateNew, a.endDateNew
        FROM    @Groups a
    ) b
) c
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT  d.Uid AS Overlapping_Uid
    FROM    @Groups d
    WHERE   c.Bkey = d.Bkey
    AND     c.startDateNew = d.startDateNew
    AND     c.endDateNew = d.endDateNew
) e

-- This returns distinct groups identified by DistinctGroupId together with an XML (XmlCol) which includes overlapping Uid(s)
SELECT  *
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY b.Bkey, b.startDateNew, b.endDateNew) AS DistinctGroupId, b.*
    FROM (
        SELECT  DISTINCT a.Bkey, a.startDateNew, a.endDateNew
        FROM    @Groups a
    ) b
) c
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT (
    SELECT  d.Uid AS Overlapping_Uid
    FROM    @Groups d
    WHERE   c.Bkey = d.Bkey
    AND     c.startDateNew = d.startDateNew
    AND     c.endDateNew = d.endDateNew
    FOR XML RAW, TYPE
    ) AS XmlCol
) e
```

[image]

Note: Last range used in my example is `'John',  5,   '2017-01-11', '2017-04-22';` and not `'John',  5,   '2017-01-10', '2017-04-22';`. Also, data type used is `DATE` and not `DATETIME[2][OFFSET]`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the tricky part of your query is being able to articulate the logic for overlapping ranges.  We can self join on the condition that a row on the left overlaps with any row on the right.  All matching rows are those which overlap.

We can think of four possible overlap scenarios:

```
|---------|   |---------|    no overlap

|---------|
       |---------|           1st end and 2nd start overlap

       |---------|
 |---------|                 1st start and 2nd end overlap

 |---------|
    |---|                    2nd completely contained inside 1st
                             (could be 1st inside 2nd also)

SELECT DISTINCT
    t.Uid
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.startDate <= t2.endDate AND
       t2.startDate <= t1.endDate
WHERE
    t1.Bkey = 'John' AND t2.Bkey = 'John'
```

This will at least let you identify overlapping records.  Updating and separating them in a meaningful way will probably end up being an ugly gaps and islands problem, perhaps meriting another question.

Comment: Take a look at the [overlap tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/overlap/info), it shoes the simplest test for overlapping elements.

Answer (score 0):

we can acheive this by doing a self join of emp table.

- a.emp_id != b.emp_id ensures same row is not joined with itself.
- remaining comparison clause checks if any row's start date or end date falls in other row's date range.

  ```
    create table emp(name varchar(20), emp_id numeric(10), start_date date, end_date date);

    insert into emp values('John', 1, '1990-01-01', '2017-01-10');
    insert into emp values( 'John', 2, '2016-11-03', '2016-11-14');
    insert into emp values( 'John', 3, '2016-11-14', '2016-12-29');
    insert into emp values( 'John', 4, '2016-12-29', '2017-01-10');
    insert into emp values( 'John', 5, '2017-01-11', '2017-04-22');

    commit;

    with A as (select * from EMP),
    B as (select * from EMP)
    select A.* from A,B where A.EMP_ID != B.EMP_ID
    and A.START_DATE < B.END_DATE and B.START_DATE < A.END_DATE
    and (A.START_DATE between B.START_DATE and B.END_DATE
    or A.END_DATE between B.START_DATE and B.END_DATE);
  ```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).